# Split on every upper-case letter unless it is preceded by a space

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string like that:

```
RegexMy RegexGoodregexNo need for Regex
```

How to split it like this?

```
Regex, My Regex, Goodregex, No need for Regex
```

My attempt didn't really work since it splits also after a space:

```js
var tmp = ("RegexMy RegexGoodregexNo need for Regex").split(/(?=[A-Z])/);
```

Comment: come on man, at least show us what you have done so far

Comment: var tmp = ("RegexMy RegexGoodregexNo need for Regex").split(/(?=[A-Z])/);
This Split on the basis of capital
Have no idea how to deal with White Space

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Awesome! in the future if you include your attempts you will be more likely to get help :)

Comment: @MKYounas Your try was good. Unfortunately, you would need a negative lookbehing which is not supported by the JavaScript regex engine: `(?<! )(?=[A-Z])`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following seems to be working fine:

```
'RegexMy RegexGoodregexNo need for Regex'.replace(/(\S)([A-Z])/g, '$1, $2');
// "Regex, My Regex, Goodregex, No need for Regex"
```

Comment: Thanks Dude
Saved Lot of me